# How to work with listener in synchronous manner?

Tags: android, listener, synchronous

*If I am not mistaken...*

If you launch listener your code continues running, and when the event occurs it triggers listener. So it is asynchronous.

What I would like to do is wrap that entire code in such way, that from external code it would look like synchronous call.

**Before (pseudo-code)**

```
listener:
   oh, we just read temperature value

listener launch:
   register listener for temperature
   continue running
   ... 
   // somewhere here the temperature is read so we can obtain the value
   ...
```

**After**

Additional wrapper of previous code:

```
while (true)
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  if (is_temperature_read)
    break;
```

and call of it:

```
temp = read_temperature()
```

To my surprise the loop runs infinitely and the temperature is never read (i.e. the listener is never triggered). Without wrapping it with such loop, it is triggered.

So how to do the correct wrapping?

### Update 1/2: real code

Now, this is based on Sherif elKhatib (all errors are mine).

main code:

```
    final Object lock = new Object();
```

part of listener:

```
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
        {
            synchronized (lock) 
            {
                read_value = event.values[0];
                sensor_manager.unregisterListener(this,proximity_sensor);
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
```

wait for listener:

```
          synchronized (lock)
          {
              try
              {
                  lock.wait();
              }
              catch (InterruptedException ex)
              {
              }
          }
```

### Update 2/2: calling from another thread

This is not solution, just a remark. If I call this synchronous wrapper from ad-hoc created new Thread it does not fall into deadlock.

So probably something else locks above code.

Answer (score 2):

You should lock the thread (if that is what you want)

Here is the code (I did not test so it might need something here or there)

```
public wrapperFunction() {
    Object object = new Object();
    call(bla_parameters, new listener() {
        public void onEnd() {
             synchronized(object) {
                 object.notifyAll();
             }
        }
    });
    try {
         synchronized(object) {
             object.wait();
         }
    } catch(Exception ex){}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still infinitive loop. Since this approach is quite short I update my post with relevant pieces.

Comment: Infinitive loop or freeze -- the effect is the same, program does not continue running.